# Getting Error on PayPal PAYEE_ACCOUNT_LOCKED_OR_CLOSED

Tags: paypal

I have implemented Paypal API in my ASP.net MVC application and I have tested it using the live api key,
At the time of payment processing I am getting an error stated 
reason=PAYEE_ACCOUNT_LOCKED_OR_CLOSED in the failure URL

[This is the page which I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1FOEM.png)

Comment: Please embed your image - its easier for people to help you Jack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the resolution for the issue
It was the account was not completely created from paypal
Thats has been resolved and now the payment is working fine....

Thanks for your response micstr